# How do I upload a video to a specific playlist?

Tags: brightcove

This is the first time I am working with Brightcove.  I have been given access to an existing account with many playlists and videos.

I am looking at the [create_video](http://support.brightcove.com/en/video-cloud/docs/javascript-media-api-examples#create_video) example.  I don't see where I am supposed to specify the playlist for the video.

How do I upload a video to a specific playlist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a tag-based "smart playlist", you just need to add the appropriate tag to the video.

```
{"method": "create_video", "params": {"video": {"name": "Name","tags": ["playlistTag"],"shortDescription": "...","itemState": ""},"token": "TOKEN","encode_to":"","create_multiple_renditions": ""}}
```

If the video is to be added to a manual playlist, use [update_playlist](https://support.brightcove.com/en/video-cloud/docs/creating-and-updating-playlists-media-api#update) after create_video.